# Redux variable text with html context

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to get the text on my page from redux state, so it can be easy changed in my backend, but the problem is that i can't use html context in this state. If i use this on my page it works fine:

`<p>some text<Link to="/contact">contact</Link>more text</p>`

but whenever i use:

`<p>{Somevariablefromstate}</p>`

with this in it: `some text<Link to="/contact">contact</Link>more text` it doesn't make it a link its just plain text, is there a way to prevent this?

I hope i explained it well enough to make it understandable!

Comment: Don't use HTML as strings, generate the correct JSX when rendering, unless you're receiving the HTML strings from somewhere else.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I am indeed receiving the html string from somewhere else

Comment: @EmileBergeron I dont think it will work with your example because dangerouslysetinnerhtml doesn't work with link

Comment: It works with anything that is HTML, though, it would definitely fail if you want a React router link...

Comment: because you're confusing JSX and HTML.

Comment: Also, you should provide a [mcve] in your question. It looks like an XY problem.

Comment: Well i did say it was the React link was not working, so is it possible to solve it another way without dangerouslysetinnerhtml? I am not that experianced with react so sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Link>` is a component which will be transformed to valid HTML - most likely some `<a>` link.
You should probably have `<a href="/contact">contact</a>` as a value of `Somevariablefromstate` variable.
Plus you should most likely use https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html for your `<p>` element so this should look like that:
`<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={Somevariablefromstate} />`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't show <Link to= etc, but the link itself doesn't work..

Comment: It looks like Link doesn't work with dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I didn't see the preview of my response and it was missing most of I wrote as syntax was the same as StackOverflow. Sorry for that and hope that ma answer is clear now

Comment: A yea now it makes a lot more sense, thank you! although using an <a> link would kinda remove the usefullness of using react router

Comment: Better option would be to send object containing for instance name and href like this: {name: "contact", href: "/contact"} Then with that data you can return <Link to={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>. This will be able to generate only links though. Maybe there is sone way to get jsx code and transform it to valid html on the fly but that would be hacky